# How to create thousands of dummy records in a table - Oracle

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, dummy-data

I am learning oracle myself with help of internet...

Now, for some scenario I need thousands of records which should be available in my table.

It is not possible to create thousands of records manually...

**Is there any tools or any other way to do the same in ORACLE 10g...**

As I said I am a novice to Oracle I need some advices from you SOF professionals....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Consider: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2151576678914  Without table structures there's not much we can do.

Comment: @@xQbert: Thanks for the link.. Anywhere I can find dummy database with lots of data...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS`, `SELECT * FROM ALL_USERS`, `SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS`  all lots of data which could be used to generate dummy data.  Just be sure not to update those system tables/views.

Answer (score 0):

This database has a [JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html). Download Eclipse, add this driver to the path and write ten lines of code to insert as much blabla as required, [here tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html). Even if you have never programmed Java before and would not try again, easy enough to do.